# Prevent Tab Bar Item's View From Taking Up Orientation Of Previous Visited View

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an iOS tabbed app with Xcode 11 and Swift 5 for iPhone. The tab bar has three items. I want two of the tab bar views to be locked up in portrait, and the last one to be locked in landscape orientation(Item 1 = portrait, Item 2 = landscape, Item 3 = portrait).

Everything is actually pretty smooth, except there's a problem. When I go from the second view item to the first or third item, the view that I've transferred to from the second item(which is always landscape) turns to landscape too. As I said, the 1st and 3rd view should be locked in portrait. So that's the problem. It's fine if I go from item 1 to 3, or 3 to 2, but if I go 2 to 1/3, the bug comes up.

Now, if I do go from 2 to 1/3, I could still turn back to portrait, and after that, views 1/3 will be locked to portrait, but still, it would begin in landscape and stay there if the user didn't turn their device to portrait.

By the way, this is my TabBarController:

```swift
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TBController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if tabBarController.selectedViewController is SecondViewController{
            return .landscapeRight
        } else if let navController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController, navController.topViewController is SecondViewController {
            return .landscapeRight
        } else {
            //Lock view that should not be able to rotate
            return .portrait
        }
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController is SecondViewController{
            OrientationLock.lock(to: .landscapeRight)
        } else if let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController, navController.topViewController is SecondViewController {
            OrientationLock.lock(to: .landscapeRight)
        } else {
            //Lock orientation and rotate to desired orientation
            OrientationLock.lock(to: .portrait, andRotateTo: .portrait)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```